# How to create a table as shown

Tags: html, css, tabular

I need to create a table as shown below using HTML & CSS.

Example :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qv235/877/ refer this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [this JQuery UI plugin](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/jqueryui).
The plugin is JQueryUI datatables.

It looks like your image you showed.

The CSS (dataTables.jqueryui.css) and JS (dataTables.jqueryui.js) file required can be directly found at [this GitHub link.](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/integration/jqueryui)

[image]

Comment: @Paulie_D Added more detail to the answer :) Do let me know if anything else need to be changed.